# Notepad++ RegEx search - Find n occurrences of a character anywhere in a line

Tags: regex, notepad++

Given these lines in a text file:

```
John|Doe |4 |1|1 |1 |0 |sometext||3251076 
Mary|Jane |5 |1|2 |1 |1 |||3251030 Henry|Smith |6 |1|1 |1 |0 |text||3254212 
Sue|Anderson.|1 |1|1 |0 |0 |||4080010
```

I need to find the line that has more than 9 pipe characters.

Using a RegEx building tool at regexr.com I only can do this:

```
^[|]{3,}$
```

Which finds the 2 instances of 3 successive pipes in the online tool, but doesn't work at all in Notepad++. That's the closest I can get.

As far as building the regex in the online tool I need to add something that specifies to find the pipe *anywhere* in the line, instead of successive instances of the pipe.

Translating that to Notepad++, however, looks to be another matter...

Comment: Try `^(?:[^|\n\r]*\|){9,}[^|\n\r]*$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one works:

```
^(?:[^|\r\n]*\|){9,}.*$
```

This matches 0 or more NON pipe followed by a pipe, 9 or more times.

Comment: This Regex doesn't work in Notepad++ given the example data. I just tested it and it's reporting Can't find the text "^(?:[^|]*\|){9,}$".

Comment: Ding Ding Ding! That last edit did it! - Thanks, @Toto! :)